# Есть ли в русском языке слово "распространимый"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Сейчас я собрался писать сообщение знакомому и решил проверить в поисковике, правильно ли я написал слово "распространимый". Оказалось, что поисковик с таким словом не знаком, и в итоге предложил мне слово  "распространяемый". В том числе, редактор текста на данном сайте не распознает слово "распространимый". Возникает вопрос, есть ли на самом деле такое слово в русском языке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всей видимости, это редко употребляемое слово, свойственное рассуждениям в научных текстах ("вывод, распространимый на другие аналогичные случаи" и т. п.). Не видно проблем в способе словообразования, да и смысл слова очевиден: *тот (напр. подход, метод), который допустимо или возможно распространить* на что-то ещё. В тексте вопроса я, скорее, придрался бы к способу употребления выражения "в том числе", чем к этому слову. Что касается поисковых систем, мне удалось найти гуглом только краткое прилагательное "распространимо", и то лишь после добавления к нему частицы "ли" ("допустимо ли"). Оно встречается, например, в книге Л.Н. Трубецкого "Учение о логосе в его истории":

> ... допустимо ли логическое обобщение такого определения,
>   распространимо ли оно вне нашего сознания на сущее вообще...

Answer (score 2):

Слово "распространимый" существует в русском языке, но встречается нечасто (Текстовый редактор, действительно, выделяет его.)
"Распространимый" нашелся в онлайн-словаре синонимов  [**sinonim.org**](http://sinonim.org/s/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)  (77 слов) и в [**Словаре русского языка XVIII века, вып. 5**](http://www.feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/04/sl510211.htm?cmd=2&istext=1):

ГЕНЕРА́ЛЬНЫЙ
3. Охватывающий все; ***распространимый*** на целое и частное; обобщающий.

Слово употреблялось раньше:

*Это — самый важный вывод, вполне **распространимый** на все остальное русское крестьянство.*
(Ленин В.И. Полное собрание сочинений. Том 46. Письма 1894 г.)

*К сожалению, этот промысел, легко **распространимый** при других более выгодных условиях, в настоящем своем виде подвержен печальной случайности...*
( ПРОТОКОЛ заседания Особого Присутствия по развитию кустарных промыслов Вологодской губернии...  4-го Декабря 1886 года. Бурачный промысел.)

Употребляется и сейчас:

*Чтобы ответить на него, сперва сошлемся на предположение Рейнбергера (Rheinberger, 1992), который, описывая научные объекты, применяет подход, потенциально **распространимый** на любые объекты экспертизы.*
( Коллектив авторов. Социология вещей (сборник статей). Стр.69)

*...позицию России, предполагающую рассматривать возможный прецедент с Косово... как универсальный, **распространимый**, в частности, на фактически отделившиеся от Грузии Южную Осетию и Абхазию.*
(Юрий Болдырев. Северный Полюс и Южный океан. 10.08.2007)

Answer (score 0):

Слово употребляется, но редко. [Примеры из Корпуса.](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F0%E0%F1%EF%F0%EE%F1%F2%F0%E0%ED%E8%EC%FB%E9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=)

Answer (score 0):

"Распространимый" используется крайне редко, чаще в официальных текстах, но слово можно найти в онлайн-словаре синонимов [synonyms.su](https://synonyms.su/%D0%A0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9) (78 слов).